# Hibernate Query Language - right outer join

Tags: hibernate

So I have an object A
And an object B

A is related to B via A.x.y.id = B.p.id

I am joining on a bunch of other things for A

So the query looks like:

"select distinct(item), otherItem from A item, B otherThing ");
        "left join item.unrelatedThing unrelatedThing "
        "... a few more left joins, for a where clause that isn't important"
        " right outer join otherThing.p p with p.id = A.x.y.id");

The problem is this right outer only gets 3 items, when there are 15 items. If I make it a left join, it gets 15 items, but the B it returns is wholly unmatched to the A.

Comment: Can you get a working query in plain SQL first and then see a gap from HQL?

Comment: OH I'LL delete this - i was accidentally doing a cross join in hql. silly me!